# KeyError using environement variable, with a system service

Tags: python, service, environment-variables

My python script use, for now, the os.environ['SECRET_KET'].
The server is launch with a system service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Escota Dev Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=vagrant
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myproject
ExecStart=/var/www/myproject/env/bin/python web/myproject_project/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
Restart=on-abort


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service is running :

```
● myproject-dev.service - myproject Dev Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myproject-dev.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since mer. 2018-09-19 10:18:35 CEST; 179ms ago
 Main PID: 10081 (python)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 1.2M
      CPU: 58ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/myproject-dev.service
           └─10081 /var/www/myproject/env/bin/python web/myproject_project/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000

sept. 19 10:18:35 vm systemd[1]: Started myproject Dev Service.
```

And finally, the error message :

```
[CRITICAL] -> 19/09/2018 09:10 : ('Environment(Config) Error ! => ', ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /firerisk/zone/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe9b4d72b38>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))",),), <class 'requests.exceptions.ConnectionError'>)
```

But it's not relevant 'cause the real error is :

```
Sep 19 10:18:39 vm python[10081]:   File "/var/www/myproject/web/myproject_project/myproject_project/settings.py", line 30, in <module>
Sep 19 10:18:39 vm python[10081]:     if os.environ['SECRET_KEY']:
Sep 19 10:18:39 vm python[10081]:   File "/var/www/escota/env/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
Sep 19 10:18:39 vm python[10081]:     raise KeyError(key) from None
Sep 19 10:18:39 vm python[10081]: KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks.

Fabrice

Answer (score 0):

It's seems the answer is that :

```
sudo systemctl set-environment SECRET_KEY=blahblahblah
```